# Set delivery confirmation on "Unsent Messages" in Thunderbird

Tags: thunderbird

I have a problem with Thunderbird! I have a program which have to send Emails with a Delivery Confirmation. So, to do this I write the Email on the "Unsent Messages" and then I will send it from "Usent Messages" section on Thunderbird. My question is: how can I set a Delivery Confirmation while I'm writing the Email?
I hope you understand my question!

Answer (score 0):

If you go to write an email as normal then go to the top toolbar and select 'Options', there should be an option called 'Delivery Status Notification'.

This will notify you when the email is successfully delivered.

I hope this answered your question.